# JLabel graphic changes at wrong time

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jframe, jlabel

I have a slot machine program with some graphics, and the graphic is supposed to change when you pull the lever and for some reason it changes the graphic after it goes through all of the other code first. Have a look:

Declare images:

```
static ImageIcon jImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\jackpotLeverNotPulled.png");
static ImageIcon jackpot1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\jackpotimage1.png");
static ImageIcon jackpotPulled = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\jackpotLeverPulled.png");
```

Now I add to panel:

```
static JLabel jlb = new JLabel(jImage);
```

Now I want the image to change when a certain area is clicked on my panel but the main jackpot code runs first and then the image changes:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        // Returns the X coordinate of where the mouse was click on the panel
        System.out.println("X Coordinate: " + e.getX() );


        //  Returns the Y coordinate of where the mouse was click on the panel
        System.out.println("Y Coordinate: " + e.getY() );    
        System.out.println();

        Scanner ansr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yesno;

        int random =  (int)(Math.random() * 21 );
        int percentCheck =  (int)(Math.random() * 10 );

        if (e.getX ()>975 && e.getX ()<1159 && e.getY ()>82 && e.getY ()<218){
            jlb.setIcon(jackpotPulled);
            if (cashMoneyz<1) {

                System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
                image1.setIcon(jackpot1);
            } else {

                System.out.println("One dollar has been removed from you slot machine balance");
                cashMoneyz--;
                try {
                    System.out.println("Spinning...");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Spinning...");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("SPINNINGGGGG...OMG SOOO INTENSE");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                }

            }   
            System.out.println("You have this much money (in dollars) left in your slot machine balance: " + cashMoneyz);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

It does the if statements and try catches and only changes the graphic to jackpotPulled at the end of everything.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 problems in your code:

**1)**
A call to `label.setImage()` won't update immediately, as this is true for everything in AWT and Swing. Any time a repaint request is fired, it is simply added to a repaint queue, that will wait patiently for all other tasks done in the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) to finish. But since you do other things in the `mousePressed()`, they will run first. A simple solution for this would be to do the computing in `mouseReleased()`. But a bigger problem exists.

**2)**
What you are currently doing is "starving" the EDT - a bad programming practice - as all screen related invocations must be executed immediately. Sleeping the EDT won't allow any repaints to take place while running. This is true for any long running tasks as well.
Its solution is to run the non-painting calls in a different thread:

```
private volatile boolean isComputing = false;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
    if(isComputing)
        return;
    isComputing = true;

    // .
    // .
    // .
    // change icon here, or any
    // other swing related change.
    // .
    // .

    // run game
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
           // all non-swing computations

           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   // change back icons,
                   // and some other swing updates
               }
           }
           isComputing = false;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't start a new thread every time the mouse is pressed. What if the user clicks again while a thread is still running?

Comment: This could be controlled with a global boolean `isComputing` checked before creating the thread, then set to `true` and change back to `false` when finished.

Comment: @alain: I often disable input while an operation is in progress. I can't think of many buttons or input objects that would allow repeated triggering while an operation is being carried out.

Comment: @Gorb I'm not saying it's impossible to do it this way, I just find it needlessly complicated because of multithreading/synchronisation issues. A roll-your-own synchronisation object like `isComputing` will not be safe in some cases, by the way.

Comment: @alain You're needlessly simplifying a real problem that OP is approaching in a fundamentally wrong way. Event handlers need to do what they need to do as quickly as possible and offload any work to other threads so they can handle more events. If he decided to add buttons to manually stop each wheel of the slot machine it would never work because the entire spin process would need to run before it could be stopped. It looks like OP's just learning so why not teach him right?

Comment: @josaphatv, did you see I posted an answer? I'm suggesting to use a timer. There is no expensive work that needs a separate thread, it's just about delaying some things. IMHO, a timer is perfect for that purpose.

Comment: @josaphatv, No, it's not multithreading. Quote from [the document you mentioned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) : _Note that the Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch thread._

Comment: @alain I counter-quote from the second paragraph: "Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing **timer thread**" [emphasis added]. The API for it is exactly the same as in this answer, except you don't need to worry about the implementation. Have a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). I'll stop "discussing in the comments" now.

Answer (score 0):

An event handler (`mousePressed`) souldn't take a long time to complete, there should be no `sleep`s in it. As long as it runs (or sleeps), nothing else can happen. The runtime is waiting for the handler to return and displays the image after that. I would move most of the code to a function called by a timer, and use a state variable to keep track of how intensely the wheels are spinning.

Comment: The try catch sleep is just part of the game. Why is it waiting until after that? I told it to change the image way before the sleep

Comment: `Thread.sleep` freezes up the current thread: in this case the AWT event thread. It can't post any new events until you finish. The event I assume is blocked is the `PaintEvent` that gets posted when you update the icon.

Comment: It seems the runtime just remembers it sould update the icon, but doesn't do it immediately. Thats quite usual.

Comment: Is there any quick fix? I'm just a highschool student and I'm not too sure how to fix that.

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry. But on the long term you will save time if you know how to design such things properly.

Comment: @user2918193 *"Is there any quick fix?"* Use a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Wouldn't creating another mouseEvent method just above that one where the graphic would be changed work?

Comment: Here's a link to Oracle's tutorial for Java Swing's GUI timers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html